# Qt: Remove escape sequence from unsigned char

Tags: c++, qt

I've encountered something strange where a value received from the hardware I have configured is being received as `\014`.

What I am doing is receiving a value from the hardware ranged from 1-12. This value is passed as a hex value and using 12 as an example, is sent from the hardware over USB as 0x0C. When it's received from the Qt application, the memory register shows:

[image]

when all I want it to show is `temp    "12"    Qstring`.

Qt code:

```
void device_reply(A *a, B *b)
{
    device *config = static_cast<device *>(b->deviceConfig);
    QString temp = a->Data.constData();
    config->band = temp;

}
```

I've been trying various methods like trying to access the `QChar` value, convert to uint and back, tried `.trimmed()` with `.right(2)` and other values, and even tried removing the escape sequence `\0` but none of these methods seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The code `0x0C` is not actually the hex representation, and is instead the ASCII representation which represents the "Form Feed" control character, not the number 12. To get the actual value of the hexadecimal string, you need to convert it to an integer then cast back to a string.

Code:

```
void device_reply(A *a, B *b)
{
    device *config = static_cast<device *>(b->deviceConfig);
    QString temp = a->Data.constData();
    QByteArray hexTemp = temp.toLocal8bit();

    config->band = QString::number((int)hexTemp[0]);

}
```